# How can i keep the input changes i'm making while changing the radio buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm having 5 inputs and 3 radio boxes and by checking on each one of i would love to make changes on the inputs, for example if I pick on the first radio button I want to change 4 inputs as selected index and keep the first one, and if I pick the second one i want all the inputs disabled except one and the same for the last radio button.

The desired goal as listed above but the problem is that when I change the buttons the inputs disabled and not works like I want and it works only when i refresh the page and choose one radio box but when I start to change to another radio box the problem occurs.

i've tried to use trigger event on all the radio buttons and each one of them but i didn't get result

Here is the HTML code:

```js
function changeState() { }

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".dropdown_inputs").hide();
  var inputField = $(".form-control");

  $(".form-check-input:checked").each(function() {
    console.log('selected value ', this.value);
  });

  // Add an event listener to the radio buttons            

  $('#option2').click(function() {
    if (this.value == "Property") {
      inputField.not("#property").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submitsProp").attr("hidden", false);
      $("#submits, #submitsIdea").attr("hidden", true);

    }
  });
  $('#option3').click(function() {
    if (this.value == "Substream") {
      inputField.not("#substream").prop("disabled", true);
      $("#submits").attr("hidden", false);
      $("#submitsProp,#submitsIdea").attr("hidden", true);
    }
  });
  $('#option1').click(function() {
    //getProperty();
    //getSubstream()
    //getType()
    //getPrinciple()
    $("#inputContainer input").attr('hidden', true);
    $("select").removeAttr('hidden');
    $("#submitsIdea").attr("hidden", false);
    $("#submitsProp, #submits").attr("hidden", true);

  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container mt-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="result alert alert-success" hidden role="alert"></div>
  <h2>Add your new tool</h2>
  <form action="add_Form.php" method="POST">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-4 mt-4">

      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="option" id="option1" value="Idea" onclick="changeState()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option1">Add an Idea</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="option" id="option2" value="Property" onclick="changeState()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option2">Add Property only</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="option" id="option3" value="Substream" onclick="changeState()">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="option3">Add Substream only</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="tool_idea">Tool/Idea:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tool_idea" placeholder="Enter an Idea" required>
    </div>
    <div id="inputContainer">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="property">Property:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="property" name="property" placeholder="Enter a property" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden id="selected_property" name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="substream">Substream:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="substream" name="substream" placeholder="Enter a substream" required>
        <select class="form-select" id="selected_substream" hidden name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="type">Type:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="type" name="type" placeholder="type" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden id="selected_type" name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="principle">Principle:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="principle" name="principle" placeholder="principle" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden id="selected_principle" name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </div>
    </div>

    <button id="submits" type="submit" hidden class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Substream</button>
    <button id="submitsProp" type="submit" hidden class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Property</button>
    <button id="submitsIdea" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Idea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as comment, no need to check the value of a radio button. as soon as clicked, means clicked!

Comment: Yup you are right thanks for notice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your requirements 100%, but here is an example of how you can hide/show parts of a form. First of all I introduce the fieldset element. It has some features like disabling. So, all the form field children of the fieldset are excluded from the submit event if the fieldset is disabled. Second, you can show/hide elements based on the disabled property. So, you don't need to show/hide elements explicitly.

If something is changed in the form, I test if the change happens to the radio buttons. If so, all fieldsets and buttons are disabled. And afterwards the relevant form fields are enabled (this is where I can't follow you description, so this is my best guess).

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  if(e.target.name == 'optiontype'){
    // disable/hide all elements
    [...form.elements]
      .filter(elm => elm.nodeName == "FIELDSET" || elm.nodeName == "BUTTON")
      .forEach(fieldset => fieldset.disabled = true);
    // enable/show only the elements needed
    form[e.target.value + 'set'].disabled = false;
    form['submit' + e.target.value].disabled = false;
    form.typeprinciple.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```css
*:disabled {
  display: none;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container mt-4 col-md-6 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
  <div class="result alert alert-success" hidden role="alert"></div>
  <h2>Add your new tool</h2>
  <form action="add_Form.php" method="POST" name="form01">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-4 mt-4">

      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <label class="form-check-label"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optiontype" value="idea" checked>Add an Idea</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <label class="form-check-label"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optiontype" value="property">Add Property only</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check mx-3">
        <label class="form-check-label"><input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="optiontype" value="substream">Add Substream only</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <fieldset name="ideaset">
      <label for="tool_idea">Tool/Idea:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tool_idea" placeholder="Enter an Idea" required>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="inputContainer">
      <fieldset name="propertyset" disabled>
        <label for="property">Property:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="property" placeholder="Enter a property" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset name="substreamset" disabled>
        <label for="substream">Substream:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="substream" placeholder="Enter a substream" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden name="selected" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </fieldset>

      <fieldset name="typeprinciple">
        <label for="type">Type:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="type" placeholder="type" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden name="selectedtype" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>

        <label for="principle">Principle:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="principle" name="principle" placeholder="principle" required>
        <select class="form-select" hidden name="selectedprinciple" aria-label="Default select example">

        </select>
      </fieldset>
    </div>

    <button name="submitsubstream" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Substream</button>
    <button name="submitproperty" type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Property</button>
    <button name="submitidea" type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-primary mx-auto mt-3">Add Idea</button>
  </form>
</div>
```